# Screen resolution stuck at 640x480 after installing Ubuntu on QEMU

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, xrandr

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 under QEMU. In the "Try Ubuntu" stage, I was able to open a terminal and get a good screen resolution using `xrandr -s 1920 1080`. Once Ubuntu is installed and I am running from the virtual hard drive, however, that command fails. `xrandr` only shows 640x480 and smaller resolutions. I can create a new mode using `xrandr --addmode` and `cvt 1920 1080`, but is impossible to apply the new mode; I get the error `BadValue (integer parameter out of range)`.

How can I get the resolution to a sane value?

This is my run script:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -m 8G \
    -enable-kvm \
    -vga std \
    -display default,show-cursor=on \
    -usb \
    -device usb-tablet \
    -machine type=q35,accel=hvf \
    -smp 4 \
    -vga virtio \
    -drive file=ubuntu-desktop-22.04.qcow2,if=virtio \
    -cpu qemu64
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out myself, and I feel pretty silly. I was able to change the size in Settings > Displays. The reason I didn't try that before is that when I tried that in the "Try Ubuntu" phase, it was impossible because the resolution didn't allow you to click accept. In the version on disk, however, you can move the window out of the area of the screen in order to find and press the button.